# Find a red rectangle on the game screen

Tags: c#, bitmap, screen, aforge

I know there's been many topics similar to this one but none of them had a precise answer to what I'm searching for so please if anybody knows, and also I'm doing it in C#.

You all probably know (FPS) games and on the game screen with resolution say 1024x768 i need to find a red rectangle(which is the enemy) and move the mouse to it. 
So my main problem is to find that red rectangle. OK so here's what I've tried so far:

I've tried the AForge and ran out of memory:

```
ExhaustiveTemplateMatching tm = new ExhaustiveTemplateMatching(0);
TemplateMatch[] matchings = tm.ProcessImage(image1.Clone(r,
        System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb), image2);
```

I've used CopyfromScreen to create a image1 and image2 is a template I have.

I've tried the LockBits, so I can create the 2 dimensional code array for a bitmap and find the code for color red and  try to ID if it's a rectangle but the idea seems very complicated been stuck here for a 4 days now.

The web is full of info on this but the more I go into the more I get confused :(

Anyway please ppl help me out here:

Comment: Making an aimbot is highly unethical

Comment: I really have hard time believing that AForge ran out of memory. How are you using it?

Comment: @GETah i've tried 2 ways : 1. http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/template_matching.html on this link, by changing value of the ExhaustiveTemplateMatching(0.485f) i am able to find something, but when i put it higher it finds nothing, when i bring it down it finds everything just too much. Can't find the middle in between. 2. and second approach i've tried to put the TemplateMatch[] matchings = tm.ProcessImage(image1.Clone(r, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb), image2);
 I've put above code into double FOR search that gave me out of memory thing.

Comment: @PoweRoy Very assumptions, but it's not a Counter Strike, Counter Strike uses AI functions as oppose to the graphical approach I'm attempting. Using this kind of aimbot in CS would be a suicide :) I'd rather let my girlfriend play.

Comment: @MandahMr. Why are you cloning `image1` all the time? Can't you just use the original image?

Comment: @GETah, yeah i've been trying to take the smaller part of the screen so it would be more comparable to the template, since i'm getting too many matches with just TemplateMatch[] matchings = tm.ProcessImage( sourceImage, template ); this. Basic idea was to break up the big screen into small images and compare each to the template, my idea is that might be more accurate. But i'm open to any suggestions, still new to C#.

Comment: @MandahMr. Have you tried changing the similarity threshold? Your code is using 0 as a threshold and that does not seem right to me

Comment: @GETah, yes i've tried that and if i go too high it finds nothing and when i bring it down it finds just too many things along with the right thing, can't find exact value that would do the trick, and also this method takes around from 5 seconds upto 5 mins depending on the resolution of the image. I dont mind if it takes around 1 second but can't spare more. The idea is quite simple  there must be something out there :-) hehe

Comment: @MandahMr. Have you tried the recommended value of 0.9f?

Comment: @GETah, yes i just tried and in that case it finds nothing at 69f it finds too many and at 70f it find only 1 but in the wrong place, and at 71f it finds nothing. I've read about this method and it seems that it uses pixels and their pattern for comparison. Meaning that it might not be the most ideal for searching something in the game screen where image will be very much diverse in terms of pixel patterns.

Comment: @MandahMr. The threshold should be in [0..1]. Also, ExhaustiveTemplateMatching processes only grayscale (8 bpp indexed) and color (24 bpp) images.

Comment: @GETah, i was referring to this // (set similarity threshold to 92.5%)
ExhaustiveTemplateMatching tm = new ExhaustiveTemplateMatching( 0.925f ); just didn't put the "0." in front of 70f. I'm not sure maybe i'm using it wrong or maybe this isn't the method i should use ?? But that's what i have so far twinkling with the comparison value.

Comment: @GETah, Also, ExhaustiveTemplateMatching processes only grayscale (8 bpp indexed) and color (24 bpp) images. :: so you mean there's no way to make it work faster for 24bpp image ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first I need to say that this will be probably slow, so if the red rectangle is moving fast, you will need some other solution. C++, CUDA, etc...

First:
Save a image of the red rectangle.
Define the area of possible locations of the red rectangle.

Steps:

1. Capture the game image (you can use Graphics CopyFromScreen).Copy only the area that the red rectangle might be, to reduce processing time.
2. Use EmguCV MatchTemplate to find the position of the red
   rectangle.
3. Move the mouse to the position.
4. Some thread sleep and Repeat 1...

To process the image use [EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com)
To control the mouse use [MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor](http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com)

Speedup note: EmguCV have some CUDA support now, so you can try to use the CUDA version of the method.

```
        //You can check if a 8bpp image is enough for the comparison, 
        //since it will be much more faster. Otherwise, use 24bpp images.
        //Bitmap pattern = "YOUR RED RECTANGLE IMAGE HERE!!"
        Point location = Point.Empty;
        //source is the screen image !!
        Image<Bgr, Byte> srcBgr = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(source);
        Image<Bgr, Byte> templateBgr = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(pattern);

        Image<Gray, Byte> src;
        Image<Gray, Byte> template;
        src = srcBgr.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
        template = templateBgr.Convert<Gray, Byte>();

        Image<Gray, float> matchFloat;
        matchFloat = src.MatchTemplate(template, TM_TYPE.CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);
        if (debug)
        {
            //matchFloat.Save(@"match.png");
            //Process.Start(@"D:\match.png");
        }
        //Gets the max math value
        double max;
        double[] maxs, mins;
        Point[] maxLocations, minLocations;
        matchFloat.MinMax(out mins, out maxs, out minLocations, out maxLocations);
        max = maxs[0];

        if (max > threshold)
        {
        location = maxLocations[0];
        //Point the mouse... Do your stuff
```